# How to expand list comprehensed for loop code?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I was trying to expand this list comprehension code to the non-pythonic regular way, but I could not do it, can anybody help?

```py
charlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
complete = []

for current in range(2):
    a = [i for i in charlist]
    for x in range(current):
        a = [y + i for i in charlist for y in a]
        complete += a
print(a)
```

I have tried this -->

```py
# password --> secr
charlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
complete = []
a=[]
for current in range(2):
    for i in charlist:
        a.append(i)
        for x in range(current):
            for i in charlist:
                for y in a:
                    a.append(y+i)
                    complete += a
print(complete)
```

But no results.

Comment: `a = [i for i in charlist]` does a complete iteration of charlist, and then iterates current, but you have it where for each letter of charlist, it iterates current. Double check the indentation of the 2nd and 3rd for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = [i for i in charlist]` is used to initialize `a`, but you add another layer of for loop for the rest of the code there when trying to initialize `a`.

Also `a = [y + i for i in charlist for y in a]` changes `a` after the calculation, but your code changes `a` while looping through `a`.

```
charlist = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
complete = []
for current in range(2):
    a=[]
    for i in charlist:
        a.append(i)
    for x in range(current):
        new_a = []
        for i in charlist:
            for y in a:
                new_a.append(y+i)
        complete += new_a
        a = new_a
```